# from a three-column data.table to a matrix

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a variable in a data.table because the syntax is more readable, but then store it in a matrix for faster access.

I've come up with a clumsy way of doing this (see the function `dt_to_mat` below) and am hoping there is a better alternative (that doesn't carry the baggage of another package or weird attributes). By 'better,' I mean easy to maintain and extend for making an array out of several data.table 'margin' columns (two for a matrix) and a single 'value' column.

```
get_w   <-  function(D,y){
    (1+c_wD*D)*(c_w0+c_w1*y)}
c_w0 = 1; c_w1 = 1; c_wD = .1
Tbar = 10L

wdt     <-  CJ(D=0:1,y=0:Tbar)[,w:=get_w(D,y)]
#     D y   w
#  1: 0 0 1.0
#  2: 0 1 2.0
#  3: 0 2 3.0
#  4: 0 3 4.0
#  5: 0 4 5.0
#  6: 0 5 6.0
#  7: 1 0 1.1
#  8: 1 1 2.2
#  9: 1 2 3.3
# 10: 1 3 4.4
# 11: 1 4 5.5
# 12: 1 5 6.6
```

...And then store it it a matrix:

```
dt_to_mat <- function(DT){
    fla <-  paste0(c(names(DT),'~','+')[c(3,4,1,5,2)],collapse="")
    out <-  xtabs(fla,DT)
    attr(out,'call') <- NULL
    attr(out,'class')<- NULL
    out
}

wmat <- dt_to_mat(wdt)
#    y
# D     0   1   2   3   4   5
#   0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
#   1 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6
```

`xtabs` (which I use here) seemed like the least terrible of the `base` reshape commands. It passes the `is.matrix()` test even without stripping its attributes, but requires the construction of a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
as.matrix(wdt[, setNames(as.list(w), y), by = D][, D := NULL])
#       0   1   2   3   4   5
#[1,] 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
#[2,] 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6
```

As per comments, it's probably better to use `acast` from `reshape2` for this:

```
library(reshape2)
acast(wdt, D ~ y)

# or for the multidimensional case
wdt2 <- CJ(D1=1:2,D2=1:2,y=1:3)[,w:=D1/D2*log(y)]
acast(wdt2, D1 ~ D2 ~ y)
```

Comment: Thanks. In my desired output, D's values are row labels, not their own column. Also, any idea how to extend this to a data.table starting with >2 'margins' (e.g., turning `wdt2 <- CJ(D1=1:2,D2=1:2,y=1:3)[,w:=D1/D2*log(y)]` into an array of values for `w`)?

Comment: @Frank edited to take out `D`, not sure about the multidimensional arrays

Comment: Okay, thanks. Another nice thing would be if I didn't have to know the column names ahead of time (just automatically taking the final column as the one for values, and the others as margins). I think maybe I'll have to bite the bullet and learn to use `acast`, which has a "margins" argument (as a retracted answer almost suggested).

Comment: @Frank you could take `names(wdt)` and extract the column names from there, but yeah `acast` is easier for this, just `acast(wdt, D ~ y)` should do it

Comment: @Frank see edit - `acast` actually works great for the multidimensional case

Comment: Okay, thanks @eddi. I'll use `acast` for now, then, though it apparently still has a mandatory formula. Strange documentation there..., with no syntax to indicate which args are mandatory or initialized.

Comment: @Frank you can always construct the formula yourself - `as.formula(paste(head(names(wdt2), -1), collapse = '~'))`; actually `acast` seems to be ok with just strings, so you don't even need the `as.formula`